# Deploying NextAuth on Firebase

Tags: firebase, next.js, next-auth

I just deployed a NextJs app with NextAuth on firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs)

I'm facing an error in the browser console.
`ext-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error` 
According to the doc you get this error when the env var `NEXTAUTH_URL` is not set. But I have it set in my .env.production. 
And when I try to login I have this error:

`Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL /api/auth/error from this server.`

NextAuth: Credentials with jwt strategy (jwt sent by my backend, `NEXT_PUBLIC_API` see below) 
My .env.production looks like this : 
`NEXT_PUBLIC_API=http://BACKEND-IP:PORT` 
`NEXTAUTH_URL=https://my-app-name-her.web.app` 
`NEXTAUTH_SECRET=long-secret-here`

What am I missing ? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, this might be the solution.

I think you have to add the domain in the **"Authorized redirect URIs"** in Google Developer Console. https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

As per NextAuth docs, https://next-auth.js.org/providers/google#configuration

The **"Authorized redirect URIs"** used when creating the credentials must include your full domain and end in the callback path. For example;

- For production: `https://{YOUR_DOMAIN}/api/auth/callback/google`
- For development: `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google`

Comment: I'm not using the Google auth provider. I'm using Credentials provider instead (https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials)